# what is $z$ in $z \ge \frac{ \prod_{j=1}^k (1+ \frac{1}{ c_j} ) - 1}{ \delta( \prod_{j=1}^k (1+ \frac{1}{\delta \cdot c_j}) - 1)}$

Tags: real-analysis

I need to find a tight $z$  as a function of $\delta$ or some constant in the following expression:
\begin{equation}
z \ge \frac{ \Big( \prod_{j=1}^k \big(1+ \frac{1}{ c_j} \big) - 1 \Big) }{ \delta \Big(\prod_{j=1}^k \big(1+ \frac{1}{\delta \cdot c_j} \big) - 1\Big)}
\end{equation}

where each $c_j \gg \delta,$ and $ ~c_j, \delta > 1 $ are real numbers.

**My attempt:**
A particular case is when all $c_j = d $, $d\to \infty$  then 
$z \ge \frac{e^{\frac{k}{d}}-1} {\delta (e^\frac{k}{d \cdot \delta } - 1)} \to 1$ for small $k$. And when $k=d$, $z\ge \frac{e-1}{\delta (e^\frac{1}{\delta} - 1) } $.

I would like to have some bound in a discrete setting (as in computer), where $c_j $ is very large but not infinity.

A second question is  to solve a little more general case:
\begin{equation}
z \ge \frac{ \Big( \prod_{j=1}^k \big(1+ \frac{1}{ c_j} \big)^{q_j} - 1 \Big) }{ \delta \Big(\prod_{j=1}^k \big(1+ \frac{1}{\delta \cdot c_j} \big)^{q_j} - 1\Big)}
\end{equation}
where $q_j>1$ is a non-negative integer number.

Comment: In the first problem, the denominator expands to $\sum_{j=1}^{k}{\frac{1}{c_j}}$+terms involving $\frac{1}{\delta}$ and its higher powers. This is decreasing in $\delta$ for $\delta>1$ and approaches $\sum_{j=1}^{k}{\frac{1}{c_j}}$ as $\delta \to \infty$. Its highest value is at $\delta=1$ so lower bound is 1.

Comment: thanks for your comment. The question wasn't stated correctly. In fact, I need to find z which is an upper bound for the r.h.s. Apologies for the mistake.

Comment: Since the expression is increasing is $\delta$, the upper bound should be the limit of the expression as $\delta \to \infty$. That is, $\frac{\prod_{j=1}^{k}{(1+\frac{1}{c_j})}-1}{\sum_{j=1}^{k}{\frac{1}{c_j}}}$.